# Deploy OpenStack with Kolla's all-in-one mode but failed while checking MariaDB port liveness

Tags: openstack

The host IP in local network is 10.10.10.5 **[A]** and I set kolla_internal_vip_address to 10.10.10.105 **[B]**. However, the MariaDB service listen at B:3306 but kolla-ansible check port liveness with A:3306.

[After executing "kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one deploy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDZwd.png)

**Error info:**

```
TASK [mariadb : Check MariaDB service port liveness] *******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 10, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for search string MariaDB in 10.10.10.5:3306"}
```

**Here is my globals.yml:**

```
  kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
  kolla_install_type: "binary"
  network_interface: "enp0s8"
  neutron_external_interface: "enp0s3"
  kolla_internal_vip_address: "10.10.10.105"  # IP [B]
```

Comment: did you found out how to fix that issue?

Comment: this problem was fixed till kolla-ansible 12.x and get showed in 13.0.0.0rc1 again!

Answer (score 0):

Add this option to your globals.yml

```
enable_mariadb_clustercheck: yes
```

It solved the problem in openstack xena and kolla-ansible 13.0.0.0rc1